# Problem related to triangle circumcentre

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In a triangle $\Delta ABC$ there are three perpendiculars $x,y,z$ from vertices $A,B,C$ respectively. Prove that $\cos A/x + \cos B/y + \cos C/z = 1/R$, where R is circumcentre of the triangle.

I can't find any suitable relationship between $\cos$ of all angles and the heights of the triangle. Any clue regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: I found out that $y = csin B$ similarly for other angles. Should I have to convert it into cos and put into the given relationship ?

Comment: what are $x,y,z$ ? your definition is ambiguous.

Comment: x,y,z are the perpendiculars on each side of the triangle from vertices A,B,C respectively

Comment: These perpendiculars are named "altitudes".

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\cos B}y=\dfrac{\cos B}{c\sin A}=-\dfrac{\cos(A+C)}{2R\sin C\sin A}=\dfrac{1-\cot A\cot C}{2R}$$

Now for $A+B+C=\pi,$

$$\cot A\cot B+\cot B\cot C+\cot C\cot A=1$$ [Proof](http://keral2008.blogspot.in/2012/02/if-abc-180-show-that-cot-cotb-cotbcotc.html)

Comment: I Thanks for the suggestion, the hint suggests the whole answer though @lab